# When colliding with another object, the variable referenced is undefined, even though it is defined? (GMS1.4)

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-1.4

I am using GameMaker Studio 1.4. I have a fireball object, and when it collides with the enemy object, it is supposed to remove 1 (one) from the enemy's life variable.

Here is the code:

### **Fireball Code**

**Step Event**

```js
if (place_meeting(x,y,obj_enemy)) { // if collision with enemy
    with (other) {
        other.life-=1; // remove 1 from life
        self.start_decay=true; // remove fireball
    }
}
```

### **Enemy Code**

**Create**

```js
life=1;
isDie=false;
```

---

**Step Event**

```js
if (life<=0) {
    isDie=true; // I use a variable because there are other conditions that can also satisfy this
}


[...] // other unnecessary code


if (isDie) {
     instance_destroy(); // Destroy self
}
```

---

### Error Log(s)

```py
___________________________________________
############################################################################################
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object obj_fireball:

Variable <unknown_object>.<unknown variable>(100017, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_obj_fireball_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 3) -         other.life-=1;
############################################################################################
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stack frame is
gml_Object_obj_fireball_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 3) ('other.life-=1;')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you're using an `other` inside a `with(other)`, which sounds a bit unneccesary.

Assuming that the `other.life -= 1` is meant for the enemy, and the `self.start_decay=true` is for the fireball, then you can remove the `with(other)` line (and brackets), keeping the code like this:

```
if (place_meeting(x,y,obj_enemy)) { // if collision with enemy
    other.life-=1; // remove 1 from life
    self.start_decay=true; // remove fireball
}
```

If you use `with(other)`, then everything inside that `with(other)` will be targetted towards the 'other' object it's colliding with, in this case, your `obj_enemy`.

Calling an `other` inside a `with(other)` will possibly be targetted back towards the fireball, which didn't defined the `life` variable. And that's where your error came from.